# Как добавить пролистывание?

Tags: html, css

Есть выдвижной чатик с ответами на вопросы и надо добавить справа (в раскрытом виде) возможность пролистывать этот чат. Вот какая штука нужна в чате [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код няглядно: `jsfiddle.net/c2s5rtyh/`

```css
.content {
    background-color: #aaeeff;
    width: 100%;    
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
.chat-wrapper, .chat-wrapper label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 294px;
}
.chat-wrapper {
    background-color: #5577aa;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: table;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3px 3px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
.chat-wrapper label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
#show_chat {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
}
#show_chat ~ .chat-wrapper label::after, #show_chat:checked ~ .chat-wrapper label::after {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;    
}
#show_chat ~ .chat-wrapper label::after {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
}
#show_chat:checked ~ .chat-wrapper label::after {
    border-top: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#show_chat:checked ~ .content {    
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
.chat-content {
    background: #fefaee;
    color: #000000;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
#show_chat, .chat-content {    
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
}
#show_chat:checked ~ .chat-wrapper .chat-content {
    height: 150px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
}


.hide {
    display: none; 
}
.hide + label ~ div{
    display: none;
}

.hide + label {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted green;
    padding: 2px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.hide:checked + label {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.hide:checked + label + div {
    display: block; 
    background: #efefef;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
    padding: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<input id="show_chat" type="checkbox" />  
    <div class="chat-wrapper">        
        <label for="show_chat">Ответы на вопросы!</label>
        <div class="chat-content">
        <br/>
            <div class="demo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hd-1" class="hide">
    <label for="hd-1" class="sender">В какие дни мы работаем?</label>
    <div>
        HTML — стандартный язык разметки документов во Всемирной паутине. Большинство веб-страниц содержат описание разметки на языке HTML (или XHTML). Язык HTML интерпретируется браузерами и отображается в виде документа в удобной для человека форме..
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hd-2" class="hide">
    <label for="hd-2">Нажмите здесь, чтобы увидеть скрытый текст №2</label>
    <div>
    CSS - CSS Cascading Style Sheets — каскадные таблицы стилей — формальный язык описания внешнего вида документа, написанного с использованием языка разметки. Преимущественно используется как средство описания, оформления внешнего вида веб-страниц, написанных с помощью языков разметки HTML и XHTML, но может также применяться к любым XML-документам, например, к SVG или XUL.
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hd-3" class="hide">
    <label for="hd-3">Нажмите здесь, чтобы увидеть скрытый текст №3</label>
    <div>
    JavaScript — прототипно-ориентированный сценарный язык программирования. Является реализацией языка ECMAScript (стандарт ECMA-262). JavaScript обычно используется как встраиваемый язык для программного доступа к объектам приложений. Наиболее широкое применение находит в браузерах как язык сценариев для придания интерактивности веб-страницам...
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hd-4" class="hide">
    <label for="hd-4">Нажмите здесь, чтобы увидеть скрытый текст №4</label>
    <div>
    jQuery — библиотека JavaScript, фокусирующаяся на взаимодействии JavaScript и HTML. Библиотека jQuery помогает легко получать доступ к любому элементу DOM, обращаться к атрибутам и содержимому элементов DOM, манипулировать ими. Также библиотека jQuery предоставляет удобный API для работы с AJAX.
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Приложите код, который Вы указали по ссылке в тело вопроса а также постарайтесь объяснить что именно Вы хотите получить в итоге и в чем будет заключаться "пролистывание"...все представляют это себе по-разному и что нужно именно Вам не всем понятно.

Comment: ок, сейчас поправлю вопрос

Comment: Она у Вас есть...просто она за границами экрана...

Comment: переопределите свойство right для враппера

Comment: `.chat-wrapper { right: 30px; }`

Comment: а вообще полосой прокрутки можно управлять с помощью css свойства `overflow`(`overflow-x` / `overflow-y`)

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, не заметил!